# is there a shortcut to delete spaces and tabs around a point in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

In emacs, there is this shortcut

```
M-\
Delete spaces and tabs around point (delete-horizontal-space).
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Deletion.html

it also works in bash. I wonder if there is an equivalent in zsh, or how to define one, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is, but you can always write it yourself as:

```
delete-horizontal-space() {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o extendedglob
  LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%%[[:blank:]]##}
  RBUFFER=${RBUFFER##[[:blank:]]##}
}

zle -N delete-horizontal-space
bindkey '\e\\' delete-horizontal-space
```

Comment: works like a charm 